# NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate crashes when called on a searched tableview

Tags: uitableview, uisearchbar, nsfetchedresultscontroller

So I nearly have this thing figured out, but I am stumbling over the NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate when I update my managedObjectContext from a detail view that was entered after searching the table.

I have a tableview generated from a core data set. I can enter a detail view from this table and make changes without any issue. I can also search the table and make changes MOST of the time without any issues. However, on certain objects, I get an "Exception was caught during Core Data change processing".

I tracked this down to the NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate. I'm using the following code:

```
case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
if (searchTermForSegue)
{
NSLog(@"index info:%@.....",theIndexPath);
NSLog(@"crashing at the next line");
[self fetchedResultsController:self.searchFetchedResultsController configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:theIndexPath] atIndexPath:theIndexPath];
break;
} else {
[self fetchedResultsController:controller configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:theIndexPath] atIndexPath:theIndexPath]; }
break;
```

When the table is not being searched, it runs the else method and that works 100% of the time. When the table is being searched, it runs the if (searchTermForSegue) and that works most of the time, but not always. I logged theIndexPath and discovered the following:

When it works, theIndexPath is correctly reporting the objects indexPat, when it fails, the wrong theIndexPath has been called. For example, if I do a search that narrows the tableView to 3 sections, 2 items in first, 1 in second, 1 in third, I get the following nslog:

```
On first object: index info:<NSIndexPath 0xb0634d0> 2 indexes [0, 0].....
on second object: index info:<NSIndexPath 0xb063e70> 2 indexes [0, 1].....
on third object: index info:<NSIndexPath 0xb042880> 2 indexes [1, 0].....
but on the last object: index info:<NSIndexPath 0x9665790> 2 indexes [2, 17].....
```

it should be calling [2, 0]

Note that I am simply updating these objects, not deleting them or adding new ones.

Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, I have figured out a hack that seems to fix the issue, but it doesn't seem like the best way to solve the problem! Any thoughts?

I discovered when NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate was called from a base table, it was only called once, but when it was called from a searched/filtered table it was called twice (seemingly 100% of the time - I suppose this is to refresh both the searched table and non-searched table?). In addition, the first call always seemed to have the incorrect indexPath while the second call had the correct information. The first call would crash the app if the incorrect indexPath was out of bounds.

My "fix" was to ignore the first call if NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate from a searched table by doing the following

adding to the interface of the tableview.h file:

```
int             changeCall;
```

then, in the tableview.m file, in loadView:

```
changeCall = 0;
```

Then I updated the NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate to this:

```
case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
        if (searchTermForSegue)
        {
            if (changeCall == 0) {
                changeCall++;
                break;
            } else if (changeCall == 1){
                NSLog(@"index infocalledtwice:%@.....",theIndexPath);
                [self fetchedResultsController:self.searchFetchedResultsController configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:theIndexPath] atIndexPath:theIndexPath];
                changeCall = 0;
                break;
            } else { break; }
        } else {
            [self fetchedResultsController:controller configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:theIndexPath] atIndexPath:theIndexPath];
        }
        break;
```

Essentially, using the changeCall int to skip the first call in a searched table update but use the second call to actually update the content. This CAN'T be the best way to fix this problem, but the bandaid seems to work. I would certainly appreciate if someone has a better answer.

In addition, by skipping the first NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate, the non-searched table is not updated to reflect the new values. I've fixed this by adding a call to reload the table in the searchDisplayControllerWillEndSearch method:

```
- (void)searchDisplayControllerWillEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
{
    [self setSearchTermForSegue:nil];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Thanks!